# How is it possible to only have one candy for a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I only have one candy for Flaaffy. How is that possible? Is it from egg hatching?

Comment: Flaaffy is a second-tier evolution (evolves from Mareep) - did you evolve a Mareep to get Flaaffy?

Comment: That must be it. I must have forgotten. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can get candy from:

- **Catching** (doubled if you use a Pinap Berry)

  - 3 candy - first-tier Pokemon
  - 5 candy - middle evolution Pokemon
  - 10 candy - final evolution Pokemon
- **Transferring** - 1 candy for each transfer.
- **Hatching**

  - 2km Egg - ~10 Candy
  - 5km Egg - ~20 Candy
  - 10km Egg - ~30 Candy
- **Buddy Pokemon** - 1 candy per milestone (with a small chance to receive 2 or more)

---

In order to have exactly 1 candy, you will have to have spent candy upgrading or evolving Mareep/Flaaffy, leaving you with 1 or 0 candy.

If left with 0 candy, you will then have had to either used a Mareep evolution as a buddy Pokemon, or transferred one Mareep or Flaaffy in order to go up to 1 candy.

#### References

- [Pokemon Go - How to get candy](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-08-12-pokemon-go-how-to-get-candy)
- [Pokemon Go - Buddy system](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-02-10-pokemon-go-buddy-system-distances-rewards)

Comment: Note that the evolution process gives you a candy afterwards, so even though Mareep takes 50 candies to evolve (I'm guessing, I don't have one yet...), if you evolve with exactly 50 candies on hand you'll still have one left over.

Comment: @Gendreavus Should be 25, then 100 for the final evolution. You're right, though, there's no way to have 0 candy and be able to see it.

Comment: @scenia D'oh, I forgot about Ampharos completely!  And I call myself a Gen-II fanboy...

Answer (score 3):

Something that everybody has possibly missed here is Powering Up. Have you Powered Up your Pokemon? When powering up, you do not gain candy again.

Comment: @Robotnik mentioned upgrading Pokemon, which is the same thing as powering up

Comment: @Wondercricket, upgrading doesn't return candy.

Comment: Oh my mistake, it already states